# How do I do this JavaScript using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

In JavaScript I can use the following code both ways, i.e:

```
var a = document.getElementById("emp").value;
document.getElementById("emp").value = a;
```

So I can basically retrieve a value as well as assign a value using ...().value

In jQuery, what is the equivalent to the above, i.e retrieve and assign?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

get value:

```
var empVal = $("#emp").val();
```

assign value:

```
$("#emp").val("this is a new value");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var a = $('#emp').val();
$('#emp').val(a);
```

The `val` accessor works like the value property, except that it's extended to work nicely even with input fields like selects and checkboxes. See [its documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/val).

Answer (score 0):

Better cache the element than the value:

```
var $a = $("#emp");
$a.val($a.val());
```